# using sqlite3 database for flaskr in python without ORM

Tags: python, flask, sqlite

Im trying to use sqlite3 for my python project. I need to make a register page to register users for accessing other features. so I need to check if the username or email exists or not . and I have been forbidden using ORM (sorry for my bad English ).the only tutorial that I have passed is this :http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/introduction/
but I dont know how to work with database,how to get table information and cells and ... 
can you please tell me how or give me a reference?
I think I must know some commands like this :

```
@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    #specially this line
    cur = g.db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)
```

Comment: Take a look at [source code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/tree/master/examples/flaskr/) from tutorial. It should help!

Comment: I have done this little app it works fine. I only want to work with sqlite3 database from my python project.

Comment: You need to know some SQL; know how to use python with sqlite3([built-in module: sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)), how to use sqlite3 with flask([Using SQLite 3 with Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/patterns/sqlite3/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it looks like this:

```
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```

More comprehensive examples could be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html